# How to get query parameters from HttpServletRequest (Tomcat 9.0)?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

The server recieves requests from two clients - Raspberry Pi and Android app, both send requests using HttpURLConnection. I need to pass parameters with theese requests, e.g:

```
http://192.168.0.10:8080/MyProject/MyServer/rpi/checktask?rpi="rpi"
```

doing it as:

```
String requestUrl = "http://192.168.0.10:8080/MyProject/MyServer/rpi";
String query = String.format("/checktask?rpi=%s",
                        URLEncoder.encode("rpi", "UTF-8"));
URL url = new URL(requestUrl + query);
conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
conn.connect();
```

The Servlet has annotation:

```
@WebServlet(name = "MyServer", urlPatterns = { "/MyServer/rpi/*", "/MyServer/app/*"})
```

But when Servlet gets request as above following happens:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

String path = request.getRequestURI();     // /MyProject/MyServer/rpi/*
String query = request.getQueryString();   // null
String context = request.getContextPath(); // /MyProject
String servlet = request.getServletPath(); // /MyServer/rpi
String info = request.getPathInfo();       // /*
}
```

Although according to those answers:
[How to use @WebServlet to accept arguments (in a RESTFul way)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31322586/how-to-use-webservlet-to-accept-arguments-in-a-restful-way)
and
[How come request.getPathInfo() in service method returns null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3745275/how-come-request-getpathinfo-in-service-method-returns-null)

it should look like this:

```
String path = request.getRequestURI();     // /MyProject/MyServer/rpi//checktask?rpi="rpi"
String query = request.getQueryString();   // rpi="rpi"
String context = request.getContextPath(); // /MyProject
String servlet = request.getServletPath(); // /MyServer/rpi
String info = request.getPathInfo();       // /checktask?rpi="rpi"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you try hitting the url manually (e.g. with a browser) does it work?

Comment: It doesn't work both from browser and app.

Comment: My answer was rubbish, sorry. I am a bit confused now and am reading the Servlet Spec, the hundredths time on this topic .... :-(

Comment: Are you really trying to pass quotes on the URL?  That's not a valid URL character.  Pass it as %34 instead.  See also [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7109143/what-characters-are-valid-in-a-url)

Comment: Are you sure that you called with the right URL, as shown in the servlet comment, first line? There is  "/*" at the end! You intended to use `checktask?rpi=rpi".    I tried your source code on a Tomcat 8 and it works out of the box.

Comment: @stdunbar No, I use URLEncoder for passing values

Comment: @gsl I don't understand what you mean by right URL. I use Tomcat 9, but will try on Tomcat 8 the same thing, may be this is the problem.

Comment: Well, deleting "name" from the annotation did solve the problem, although I have no idea why.

Comment: Have a look at [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6535676/webservlet-annotation-with-tomcat-7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6535676/webservlet-annotation-with-tomcat-7), it discusses the "name" attribute of the @WebServlet annotation.

Answer (score 20):

Your URL string is

```
http://192.168.0.10:8080/MyProject/MyServer/rpi/checktask?rpi="rpi"
```

The name of the parameter in the above String is "**rpi**".

The below code will give you the required value of the parameter "rpi".

```
String rpi = request.getParameter("rpi");
```